# WPF fill stack panel with buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating buttons during runtime, calculating the size of StackPanel and dividing with button size and then adding buttons to the StackPanel.

Now I would like final result to look like this:

```
********
**BBBB**
**BBBB**
**BBBB**
********
```

Now, with StackPanel i am getting this:

```
********
**    **
**BBBB**
**    **
********
```

Is StackPanel proper control to do this kind of work?

Code below is for another StackPanel (which works) but buttons are added verticaly:

```
*****
**B**
**B**
**B**
*****
```

This is in Program.cs

```
 private void addButtonGrp()
    {

        //Calculate size of container to determine number of buttons
        int btnMinimumHeightSize = 30;
        int btnNumberCreated = (Convert.ToInt16(rctGrupe.Height) / btnMinimumHeightSize);  

        for (int i = 0; i < btnNumberCreated ; i++)
        {


            CreateGroupButtons btn = new CreateGroupButtons();
            var btnX = new Button();

            btnX=(btn.addButton(i,btnMinimumHeightSize,Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.Width)));
            btnX.Click += ClickHandler2;

            if (i==btnNumberCreated -1 )
            {
                btnX.Height = btnMinimumHeightSize + ((Convert.ToDouble(rctGrupe.Height) / btnMinimumHeightSize) % 1)*(btnNumberCreated);
            }

            stPanel.Children.Add(btnX);
        }
    }
```

And this is in class CreateGroupButtons

```
public Button addButton(int num, int btnHeight, int btnWidth)
    {

        var btnX = new Button { Content = "Group " + num, Tag = num, Height = btnHeight, Width=btnWidth };
        return btnX;
    }
```

Comment: it would be interesting to have some code to look....

Comment: A grid seems to be a better fit...

Comment: As a note, do not create UI elements like Buttons in code behind. Instead, use an ItemsControl with a Button in its ItemTemplate. If you need some other Panel than the default StackPanel, set the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel property. Read the [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) article.

Comment: You probably want to use a UniformGrid.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for reading material and suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example of filling a UniformGrid with a 4x3 grid of Buttons:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="buttonGrid">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" ContentStringFormat="Group {0}"
                    Click="ClickHandler2"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Set the ItemsSource property to an `IEnumerable<int>` like this:

```
buttonGrid.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
```